# JOLT add value if key doesn't exists

Tags: json, key, specifications, jolt

I'm having some issues with this Jolt **input**, I'll try to be blunt.

```json
{
  "Root": [
    {
      "key1": "value1",
      "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see I have an array, 2 objects inside. This is my Jolt **spec** :

```json
    [{
      "operation": "shift",
      "spec": {
        "Root": {
          "*": {
            "key1": "newkey1",
            "key2": "newkey2"
          }
        }
      }
    }]
```

and the **output** is clearly this:

```json
{
  "newkey1": ["value1", "value1"],
  "newkey2": "value2"
}
```

Now, my question is: is it possible to add an empty value in the `"newkey2"` array when the key doesn't exists in the input JSON?

I need something like this:

```json
{
  "newkey1": ["value1", "value1"],
  "newkey2": ["", "value2"]
}
```

It maybe something easy to do, but I'm just getting the hang of Jolt.

Answer (score 1):

"Fix" the data before you have shift do it's work.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Root": {
        "*": {
          // Assuming you know the keys
          //  you expect to be in the data,
          //  add default values if they don't
          //  exist.
          "key1": "",
          "key2": ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Root": {
        "*": {
          // Now "shift" to the new format
          // "knowing" that all the keys will
          //  have at least default values.
          // Also, make "newkey1" always be 
          //  an array.
          "key1": "newkey1[]",
          "key2": "newkey2[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **`~`** operator within a **modify** transformation spec to make it default based on its existence such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-default-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Root": {
        "*": {
          "~key2": "" // if "key2" does not exist or is null, then default it to be ""
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Root": {
        "*": {
          "*": "new&" // accumulate values under common keys while prefixing their names with "new" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```